# Composing Redux Toolkit generic higher-order reducers into a meaningful state hierarchy with configureStore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm returning to [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) + [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to manage some React app state.

I'm trying to get my head around generic reducers, specifically for slices of state that share the same reducer logic and state structure. Namely an "uploaded files" slice, representing files that have been uploaded to a server/local store. Having read [this section of the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#wrapping-createslice) about re-using reducer logic, I came up with this higher-order reducer:

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction, SliceCaseReducers, ValidateSliceCaseReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface UploadFilesState {
  files: {
    type: 'font'|'image'
    fileName: string
    filePath: string
  }[]
  maxFiles: number
}

export const createUploadFilesSlice = <
  Reducers extends SliceCaseReducers<UploadFilesState>
>({
  name = '',
  initialState,
  reducers,
}: {
  name: string
  initialState: UploadFilesState
  reducers?: ValidateSliceCaseReducers<UploadFilesState, Reducers>
}) => {
  return createSlice({
    name,
    initialState,
    reducers: {
       fileUploaded(state: UploadFilesState, action: PayloadAction<UploadFilesState['files'][0]>) {
        if (state.files.length < state.maxFiles) {
          state.files.push(action.payload)
        }
      },
      ...reducers,
    },
  })
}
```

But I'm stumped as to how to use it with `configureStore()` and the state structure I would like. For example, my global state should look something like this:

```js
// Written as a Typescript interface to visualise the shape of the store
{
  appName: string
  defaults: {
    background: {
      colour: string
      images?: /* Using my generic uploadFileSlice here */
    }
    fonts: /* Using my generic uploadFileSlice here */
  }
}
```

How would I utilise my genric slices with Redux Toolkit's `configureStore()` method? For example, something like this:

```js
export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    appName: /* Some string reducer */
    defaults: {
      background: {
        colour: /* some colour reducer */
        images: createUploadFilesSlice({ name: 'defaultBackgroundImages', initialState: { files: [], maxFiles: 1}})
      }
      fonts: createUploadFilesSlice({ name: 'defaultFonts', initialState: { files: [], maxFiles: 2}})
    }
  },
})
```

The above throws. Is it that I can't be allowed to nest reducers in object literals in this way? Should I be instead creating very flat structures like:

```js
{
  appName: string
  defaultBackgroundColour: string
  defaultBackgroundImages: /* Using my generic uploadFileSlice here */
  defaultFonts: /* Using my generic uploadFileSlice here */
}
```

It's been a while since I've used Redux so I'm unfamiliar with what the limitations are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue here is that the Redux core `combineReducers` method is not recursive - it accepts an object with a single level of `sliceName: someSliceReducer` pairs.  When the `reducer` field in `configureStore` is given an object, it really just passes that on to `combineReducers` so you don't have to call that yourself.

If you want to have some additional levels of nesting that way, you'd need to call `combineReducers` yourself a couple of times, like this:

```js
const backgroundReducer = combineReducers({
  color: colorReducer,
  images: createSomeReusableReducer("images")
})

const defaultsReducer = combineReducers({
  background: backgroundReducer,
  fonts: createSomeReusableReducer("fonts")
})

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    appName: appNameReducer,
    defaults: defaultsReducer
  }
})
```